# Where to find stereo test sequences in yuv

Tags: video-processing, stereo-3d

Where can I find YUV stereo test sequences?  I have to use it for disparity compensation so I'll be needing the seprate left and right views. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 digital libraries, which contain uncompressed stereo video in YUV 4:2:0 with separate-left-right-views format:

http://sp.cs.tut.fi/mobile3dtv/stereo-video/

FTP-download only, video resolution for YUVs is ~480x270. These sequences are not copyright-free, so contacting license file is useful.

---

http://nma.web.nitech.ac.jp/fukushima/multiview/multiview.html

Here you need 'Multiview sequence 1' and 'Multiview sequence 2'

HTTP-download possible. These sequences are actually multiview, it means they contain not only left and right views, but more of them. Any 2 views from there will be fine as stereo video.

---

RMIT3dv library may also be useful, but it contains uncompressed YUV 4:2:2 video in .MOV format, so you will need to perform some format conversion to get .yuv files. But video quality on this site is way better.

Link to this library will be the first answer to 'RMIT3dv' request to google.